# MySQL Recursive Get Right Nodes PHP

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree

I have a table containing user id with left node and right node (Both are which user id). I am trying to create a function to count all the right nodes and total nodes of a particular user id in PHP.

The Code I have written till now which is always returning 0  :

```
function allcount($id)   //Function to calculate all children count
{
$sqlz = "SELECT * FROM user_transaction_details WHERE user_id = '$id'";
$execsql = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlz);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($execsql);
echo $sqlz;
(array_count_values($array));
$count = 0;
echo $array['l_node'];
if(!empty($array['l_node']))
{
    $count += allcount($array['l_node']) +1;
}
if(!empty($array['r_node']))
{
    $count += allcount($array['r_node']) +1;
}
return $count;
}
```

Here is the table structure :

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPtAu.png)

Can anybody please help.

Comment: are you getting $Id properly ???

Comment: Yes, calling it like allcount("114421"); .

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$conn` as an argument or declare it as global inside the function, because otherwise it is not available inside the function.